# How to add active class on JQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

i am searching for a vertical Jquery Accordion menu in google and atlast i found a code for what i am need in my site. I am not much experienced in Javascript. So that, from my Javascript code i need to add a "Active" class for the active tab. Can anyone help me.

**Html**

```
<div class="accordian">
    <ul>
        <li class="even" style="padding-left: 30px; cursor: pointer;">Quisque at erat vitae</li>
        <li class="dimension" style="display: block;">Test1</li>
        <li class="odd" style="cursor: pointer; padding-left: 10px;">Sed euismod massa</li>
        <li class="dimension" style="display: none;">Test2</li>
        <li class="even" style="cursor: pointer; padding-left: 10px;">Proin et orci sit amet</li>
        <li class="dimension" style="display: none;">Test3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
<style type="text/css">
.accordian {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.accordian li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.dimension {
    height: 400px;
}

.even, .odd {
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 27px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.even {
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    background-color: #ececec;
}

.odd {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    // Hide all the content except the first
    $('.accordian li:odd:gt(0)').hide();

    // Add a padding to the first link
    $('.accordian li:first').animate( {
        paddingLeft:"30px"
    } );

    // Add the dimension class to all the content
    $('.accordian li:odd').addClass('dimension');

    // Set the even links with an 'even' class
    $('.accordian li:even:even').addClass('even');

    // Set the odd links with a 'odd' class
    $('.accordian li:even:odd').addClass('odd');

    // Show the correct cursor for the links
    $('.accordian li:even').css('cursor', 'pointer');

    // Handle the click event
    $('.accordian li:even').click( function() {
        // Get the content that needs to be shown
        var cur = $(this).next();

        // Get the content that needs to be hidden
        var old = $('.accordian li:odd:visible');

        // Make sure the content that needs to be shown 
        // isn't already visible
        if ( cur.is(':visible') )
            return false;

        // Hide the old content
        old.slideToggle(500);

        // Show the new content
        cur.stop().slideToggle(500);

        // Animate (add) the padding in the new link
        $(this).stop().animate( {
            paddingLeft:"30px"
        } );

        // Animate (remove) the padding in the old link
        old.prev().stop().animate( {
            paddingLeft:"10px"
        } );
    } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear which element you want to add the class to - the tab that's been clicked, or the content that is revealed by that tab.

If you want the tab itself, use: `$(this).addClass("current");`, but if you want the content, use: `$(this).next().addClass("current");`.

You also almost certainly want to remove it as well, with `old.removeClass("current");`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p78Q9/)